# Angular CanDeactive route guard cancel behaviour

Tags: javascript, angular, browser

I have an Angular 8 app with a route guard which prevents the user from navigating away from a page if they have made changes -

```
export interface ComponentCanDeactivate {
  canDeactivate: () => boolean | Observable<boolean>
}

@Injectable()
export class PendingChangesGuard implements CanDeactivate<ComponentCanDeactivate> {
  canDeactivate(component: ComponentCanDeactivate): boolean | Observable<boolean> {
    return component.canDeactivate() ? true : confirm('Warning: You have unsaved changes. Press Cancel to go back or OK to lose these changes.');
  }
}
```

Then in my router

```
{
  path: 'pageone',
  component: PageOneComponent,
},
{
  path: 'pagetwo',
  component: PageTwoComponent,
},
{
  path: 'pagethree',
  component: PageThreeComponent,
  canDeactivate: [PendingChangesGuard]
},
```

And my component

```
export class PageThreeAddComponent implements OnInit, ComponentCanDeactivate {
  someForm: FormGroup;
  ...
  canDeactivate(): boolean | Observable<boolean> {
    return this.someForm.pristine;
  }
  ...
}
```

The guard works fine, I make changes to the form the browser prompts me when I hit the back button. However if I follow this flow

1. PageOne
2. Nav to PageTwo
3. Nav to PageThree
4. Make change
5. Click back
6. Click Cancel
7. Click back again
8. Click Ok

At this point I'm taken back two steps to PageOne. What is going on here? Why I am not returned to the previous page? It's like the browser doesn't realise the back request was cancelled. Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: Any stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y8fanr), where we can test this issue?

Comment: Weirdly the whole page is refreshed when navigating back in stackblitz so I don't it will demonstrate the issue - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b9thtu.